# entry-wise comparison between two lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists of the same length. I would like to compare them entrywise, and count how many are equal.

```
>>> lst1 = (1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1)
>>> lst2 = (0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1)
>>> for i in range(0,len(lst1)):
...     lst1[i]==lst2[i]
... 
False
False
False
True
True
False
True

>>> for i in range(0,len(lst1)):
...     if lst1[i]==lst2[i]:
...         ct = ct+1
... 
>>> ct
3
```

I wonder if it is possible to implement it more efficiently?

The following is not working, and I am not sure how it compares:

```
>>> lst1==lst2
False
```

Is it possible to use list comprehension to compare their corresponding entries? Thanks!

Comment: thanks. How do you create the list versions then? @aj8uppal

Comment: `list((1, 5, 7, 2))`gives `[1, 5, 7, 2]`

Comment: Like this: `lst1 = [1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1]; lst2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using a generator expression that checks whether each pair is equal (evaluating to `True`) or different (evaluating to `False`) and then sums up the results, using the fact that `True` also evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0`:

```
lst1 = (1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1) # by the way: these are tuples, not lists
lst2 = (0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1)
sum(x == y for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2))
=> 3
```

Comment: @Tim because that will create an intermediate list that will be wasted , we only need the list temporarily for taking the sum of the elements. By using a generator expression we're harnessing the power of iterators, which are more memory-efficient

Comment: if lst1 and lst2 are lists, will sum(x == y for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2)) still work?

Comment: @Tim indeed, both are just iterable objects and work all the same. Try it, in the list declarations replace the `()` with `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The zip code takes longer:

```
import timeit

lst1 = [1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1]
lst2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1]

def f1(lst1, lst2):
    ct = 0
    for i in range(len(lst1)):
        if lst1[i]==lst2[i]:
            ct += 1
    return ct

def f1_test():
    f1(lst1, lst2)

print(timeit.timeit('f1_test()', setup="from __main__ import f1_test"))

2.560514380413868
```

---

```
def f2(lst1, lst2):
    return sum(x==y for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2))

def f2_test():
    f2(lst1, lst2)

print(timeit.timeit('f2_test()', setup="from __main__ import f2_test"))

2.8660979345097215
```

Comment: You should always mention the version that was used for performing a benchmark in Python, because performance will depend on it. In Python 3.x, `zip` is implemented as an iterator and will be faster. In Python 2.x `zip` will return a list, but if good performance is required then `itertools.izip` should be used.